# NestedScrollView Having Constraint Layout not scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

My xml is composed by one constraint layout. Inside this there are 2 buttons and 1 nested scroll view. Inside the `ScrollView` there are various elements including recycle view. I would like that the recycle view not scroll but scroll only the nested scroll view. I have disabled the scroll of recycle view in this mode 
(`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`)
but the problem is that the nested scroll view not scrolling. Can you help me?
I attach the code below.

The code start in this mode :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/azzera"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_4lati"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/azzurro"
    android:elevation="@dimen/dimen8"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen8"
    android:text="@string/azzera"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/conferma"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_4lati"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/azzurro"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen8"
    android:text="@string/conferma"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:elevation="@dimen/dimen8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mostraPreferiti"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/mostraPreferiti"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/creditiEcm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/creditiECM"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/zero"
            android:text="@string/editText"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/creditiEcm"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view1"
            android:autofillHints="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMeno"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_azzurro_24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/azzurro"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonPiu"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPiu"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_azzurro_24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/azzurro"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mostraCorsiPassati"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/mostraCorsiPassati"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view2" />


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view2" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view3" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/professioni"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/professione2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="@font/sanfrancisco"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mostraCorsiPassati" />


        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.557"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/professioni"
            app:queryHint="Cerca..">

        </SearchView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listProfessioni"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchBar"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/professioniNonDisponibili"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/professioniNonDisponibili"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/dimen20"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/dimen12"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/error" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/error"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen80"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen80"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_error_outline_gray_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/TODO"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/searchBar"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.105" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:minWidth="80dp"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/searchBar"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.168" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: have you tried Relative or Linear Layout inside NestedScrollVIew ?

Comment: no because I need a constraint, do you think this is the problem?

Comment: yes i think so. i have seen similar problem before and someone said try Linear layout and OP said Yes this fixed my problem. but both dont know why . LOL

Comment: Yes I fixed it. I insert a linear and insert in the constraint. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Great. Good work !!

Comment: Thanks, can u say how to set the item click of a recycler view?

Comment: post another question. it has long explanation. i will explain it there,

Comment: [Adding RecyclerView Item Click Listener](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) follow this will surely help you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**As i answered in comments**

For Someone other facing same problem. This might help.

For some reasons `ScrollView` doesn't scroll when having `ConstraintLayout` inside it.

For Workaround we can use `LinearLayout`    or `RelativeLayout`instead of ConstraintLayout inside `ScrollView`. OR

As OP does put the `ConstraintLayout` inside `Linear or Relative Layout` does the trick.

Answer (score 8):

According to Ali Ahmed's answer, a `ScrollView` doesn't scroll if you have a `ConstraintLayout` inside it. Well that's not true. I have been using `ConstraintLayout` inside `ScrollView` and everything works perfectly fine. Well the problem with the code that you posted is that you are using `0dp`as the `layout_height` of your `RecyclerView`. `0dp` means `match_parent`. You should be using `wrap_content` as your `layout_height`. So that the `RecyclerView` expands its height according to the elements in it. Doing so will make your code work fine.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just tried it and it's working like a charm. This should be accepted answer.